# "Range Based for loops not allowed in C++98 mode" Error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++

I m trying to learn vectors and happened to come across this code, I tried building it in Visual Studio Code but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

This was the error message as shown in the problem tab
[image: This was the error message as shown in the problem tab]

This was the error message as shown in the Terminal after Building
[image: This was the error message as shown in the Terminal after Building]

I googled the error message, but I couldn't seem to find anything that would have solved this problem in VS Code.
I am aware that the for loop can be written in the basic simpler form but is there anyway to make this format work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector <int> vecOfInts(5);
    for (int x: vecOfInts)
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an old compiler which doesn't enable C++11 by default. Update the compiler (GCC uses C++14 by default starting from GCC 6.1) or add `-std=c++11` to build options.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen okayy! Should i add this command in the tasks.json?

Comment: The recent g++ compiler seems to be gcc 10.2. It has encompassing C++17 support and offers `-std=c++20` (which enables parts of the upcoming new C++20 standard). FYI: [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html). If anyhow possible, I would recommend an update. (Not that you have to pay for this.) ;-)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you! Adding the command in the args inside Tasks.json solved the issue

Comment: @Scheff Thank you! I will try to update it asap. :)